# How do I make a loop jupyter notebook run?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a loop for a digital humanities course that allows me to process an entire data set at once. I was provided a non-working jupyter notebook that had a code I could use to do this.

```
cleanedtextdirectory = corpora + 'working_set_cleaned/'

filenames =       #Get a list of the filenames in the `working_set` directory

for i in filenames:
    objName = open(i, "r")
    readObjName = objName.read()
    txt =         #Remove punctuation and lowercase each character, then them into a single string
    txt = regex.sub(" ", txt)
    file = open(cleanedtextdirectory + str(i),"w")
    file.write(txt)
    file.close()
print("Done! Check out " + cleanedtextdirectory + " on your hard drive to see the results.")
```

Every time I try to run this in jupyter notebook with a few changes it says that there is no "w" or "r" directory. What does "w" and "r" represent?

I tried to do

```
filenames =      "working_set"
for i in filenames:
    objName = open(i)
    readObjName = objName.read()
    txt =  ''.join(c for c in working_set if c not in punctuation).lower()
    txt = regex.sub(" ", txt)
    file = open(cleanedtextdirectory)
    file.write(txt)
    file.close()
print("Done! Check out " + cleanedtextdirectory + " on your hard drive to see the results.")
```

but when I ran this in Jupyter notebook, it said that there was no "w" or "r" directory. It was supposed to give me a file of clean documents.

Comment: What your are reporting as an error doesn't look like it matches your code? In Python, the 'w' after the path means 'write'. And the 'r' after means you are setting it to 'read' the content from the file path in front of the comma. Make your code something you can share entirely and paste the error traceback fully. too. You should be able to find lots of examples of using Python to read files in StackOverflow and elsewhere on the internet. This is pertinent to the Python you are running in your notebook and **not Jupyter**, unless you are trying to access somewhere your Jupyter environment ...

Comment: <continued> cannot see. You can tell because you'd probably encounter the same thing if you were using the Python code directly in the Python console, a.ka., interpreter, or Python scripts. Use Python or IPython separate from Jupyter to test and if you don't know how, research it, or ask your instructor. You should be able to debug this be adding print statements and making your code much more simple and only doing single steps at a time and then building on that. In Jupyter or IPython, use `pwd` and `ls` to check where you are and what you can see; use `%cd` to change directories.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on a file I did not see before.

```
> cleanedtextdirectory = corpora + 'working_set_cleaned/'
> 
> filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")
> 
> for i in filenames:
>     objName = open(i, "r")
>     readObjName = objName.read()
>     txt = ''.join(c for c in readObjName if c not in punctuation).lower()
>     txt = re.sub(" ", txt)
>     file = open(cleanedtextdirectory + str(i),"w")
>     file.write(txt)
>     file.close() print("Done! Check out " + cleanedtextdirectory + " on your hard drive to see the results.")
```

This resulted in

```
> Done! Check out home/Downloads/Digital_Humanities_2-main/dh2/corpora_and_metadata/working_set_cleaned/ on your hard drive to see the results.
```